# error 405 method not allowed IIS 8.5 SLIM

Tags: rest, iis, http-headers, slim

Im using slim framework, and IIS 8.5 in my application,

Request PUT, DELETE return error 405.. method not allowed

my web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
        </modules>
         <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
            <handlers>
              <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
              <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
              <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
            </handlers>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="slim" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

check return
[print screen headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juBao.jpg)

update.. http PUT using angularjs

```
$http.put("./slim/biblioteca/usuario/", $scope.usuario).
     success(function(data){
         ...
     }).
     error(function(data, status){
         $scope.mensagemErro = data;
});
```

update.. routes

```
$app->group("/usuario", function() {

    $this->post("/", function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {...}

    $this->put("/", function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {...}

    $this->delete("/{id:[0-9]+}/{idUser:[0-9]+}", function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {...}

});
```

Comment: show us your routes.

Comment: Ok @jmattheis check now update